# Choose block print section of file between two regular expressions using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p'

pattern1   
a   
b   
pattern2   
cd   
pattern1   
ef    
pattern2    
gh    
pattern1     
ef     
pattern2
```

This will generate the output between all matching pattern1 and pattern2

But how can i choose which block to print like only print the last matching pattern block or the first matching pattern block only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Print the Nth occurrence

Here's one way you could do it using awk:

```
$ awk '/pattern1/{++f;p=1}p&&f==2;/pattern2/{p=0}' file
pattern1
ef
pattern2
```

The number `2` in the middle controls which occurrence is printed (in this case, the second).

#### Explanation

When the opening pattern is matched, `f` is incremented and the `p` flag is set. When the closing pattern is matched, the `p` flag is unset. Lines are only printed when the `p` flag is set and `f` has a specific value.

If you wanted, you could pass the value in from the shell:

```
$ c=2
$ awk -v c="$c" '/pattern1/{++f;p=1}p&&f==c;/pattern2/{p=0}' file
pattern1
ef
pattern2
```

---

### Print the last occurrence

To always print the last occurrence within the range, you could use an array:

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$0}/pattern1/{s=NR}/pattern2/{e=NR}END{for(i=s;i<=e;++i)print a[i]}' file
pattern1
ef
pattern2
```

#### Explanation

Every line in the file is stored sequentially in the array `a`. `s` and `e` are overwritten with the current line number NR every time the start or end pattern is matched. At the end, print the elements that you're interested in.

A potential disadvantage of this approach is that the contents of the entire file are stored in memory but unless you have very large files, this may not be a problem.

Comment: This code works fine for the first block but how can i know the last number of the matching pattern block?

Answer (score 1):

Another awk way

---

#### Find the nth occurence

```
awk -vM=2 '(x+=/pattern1/)==M&&x+=/pattern2/' file
```

#### Output

```
pattern1
ef
pattern2
```

#### Explanation

```
-vM=2
```

Set M to whatever occurence you want to find

```
(x+=/pattern1/)==M
```

Increments `x` for every occurence of `pattern1` and checks if it equals `M`.

```
&&x+=/pattern2/
```

If it does then increment it for every occurence of `pattern2` so when it reaches pattern 2 it wil print that line but no more as it will now be larger than M.

Default action for awk is print.

---

#### Print the last occurence

This only stores the last block seen in memory.

```
awk 'x+=/pattern1|pattern2/{!y++&&B="";B=B?B"\n"$0:$0;x==2&&y=x=0}END{print B}' file
```

#### Output

```
pattern1
ef
pattern2
```

#### Explanation

Increment x for every occurence of pattern1 or 2
Flush B when y is not set(when a new set is found) then set y
If x exists then add lines to the variable B
Unset x and y if the count is 2 meaning both have been seen.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

### Printing the last match:

```
perl -ne 'push @keep, $_ if (/pattern1/ and @keep = ("")) .. /pattern2/;
          }{ print @keep'
```

Explanation: The match is stored in @keep, which is emptied when `pattern1` is matched. So, @keep will contain the last match after the whole input is processed.

### Printing n-th match:

```
perl -ne 'push @keep, $_
              if (/pattern1/ and ++$c and @keep = "")
              .. ($e = /pattern2/);
          print(@keep), last if $e and 2 == $c'
#                                      ^
#                                      |
#                                the second match
```

$c counts the matches. $e signals the end of the match.

Comment: i am sorry but i never used perl before